# Rtsp stream from Samsung SNB-5000

Tags: c#, stream, vlc, rtsp, ozeki

I need to access a **RTSP** stream from a **Samsung SNB-5000** video camera. The  **RTSP** link has this pattern:

***rtsp://xx.xx.xx.x:yyy/onvif/profile/media.smp***, yyy being the port.

I have tried:

**Ozeki SDK**: The link requested is just rtsp://xx.xx.xx.x:yyy, my link format renders it unusable;

**VlcdotNet**: It is great, hoewever, all tutorials refer to an old version and I could only find the new version of the library which has no tutorials;

Vlc C# plugin(**AXVLC**): deprecated;

**ispy SDK**: could not find any tutorial;

The video format I can obtain is either **H.264** or **MJPEG**. 
As you can see, I am not a PROgrammer, I am rather newb.

Help would be really appreciated.

BTW: I saw a similar question on StackOverflow, to which a foo bar guy replied something as: don't do it yourself if you are newb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **ISpy** to access the **RTSP** stream. You can get the demo plugin example from their site, in which you will find a method **ProccessFrame**, which you can use to access the **RTSP** frame as a **Bitmap**.